# Normalize vector according to ellipse

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I have an ellipse (of width $w$ and height $h$) centered in $c$ and a vector $v$ (whose origin is $c$).

[image]

$v$ can cross the ellipse or not. My objective is to find out the point where $v$ touches (or would touch) the ellipse if it was at least big enough to touch it.

[image]

Comment: Assuming you are in 2D, then the vector $v$ can be written in the form $(t, \alpha t)$ for some variable $t$. You have the equation of the ellipse. Plug in the point $(t, \alpha t)$ and solve the quadratic for $t$.

Comment: Where is $c$?  Why is $v$ the label of the center?  And what have you tried?  Where did you encounter difficulties?

Comment: $c$ is the center of the ellipse, where $v$ is written. I wrote $c$ in the center just to emphasize that it goes from the center to somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{v_y}{v_x}=\frac{h\sin\theta}{w\cos\theta}$$ gives

$$\tan\theta=\frac{v_yw}{v_xh}.$$

So $$h\sin\theta=\frac{v_ywh}{\sqrt{v_y^2w^2+v_x^2h^2}},
\\w\cos\theta=\frac{v_xwh}{\sqrt{v_y^2w^2+v_x^2h^2}}.$$